# Were there any novels ever written in the Terra Nova TV series setting?

Tags: novel, terra-nova

Was interested in reading any books written in the 2011 Terra Nova TV Series. But in doing a few google searches, I could not find anything. Not even a Novelization of the series

I was surprised that I was not able to find anything.

I am looking for Published novels Not Fan Fiction.

If there were no books ever published, is the reason why known?

Comment: Because it was bad, tanked in its first season and got cancelled?

Comment: @Valorum Ok I agree the plots of the episode were pretty bad.. And the flip flop of kill dinos this week, not kill them next week was bad... But I thought the premises of the series could have led to a decent series of books.

Comment: I've contacted the showrunners and the producers. Hopefully one of them can let us know if there were ever any plans for a book series. I strongly suspect the answers is "hell no".

Comment: I think part of the reason it got axed was the production costs per episode which iirc were very expensive

Comment: @SpacePhoenix - The ratings didn't justify the cost, according to Deadline.com - *"In the end, Terra Nova, whose budget was $14 million for the two-hour pilot and about $4 million for the subsequent episodes, not including Australian tax breaks, premiered last fall with one of Fox’s most hyped launches. It was a steady but modestly-rated performer and a big DVR gainer. The series two-hour season finale drew a 2.2/6 in adults 18-49 and 7.2 million viewers, in line with the show’s season average, which wasn’t big enough to seal a renewal but not too small to warrant an automatic cancellation."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no. No books or novelisations exist in the same universe as Terra Nova with the sole exception of a '[Make your own motion comic](https://terranova.fandom.com/wiki/Terra_Nova_Motion_Comic)' featurette that was available on the show's website, allowing you to make a 'final episode' that you could upload to the show's youtube channel.

I've sent messages to the show's creators but have yet to receive any word as to why no further media was made for the show. I can only assume that it was because the series was cancelled mid-season in its first year.